# To click on the check box of all　[Ruby Selenium-webdriver]

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Button as shown below is lined in large quantities.
Button or decrease it or increase depending on the day.
contents of "value" only changes.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="021258" name="xbutton"></input>
<input type="checkbox" value="084192" name="xbutton"></input>
<input type="checkbox" value="095842" name="xbutton"></input>
<input type="checkbox" value="096325" name="xbutton"></input>
...
...
```

I would like to operate like to check all of this.
I think so that it can respond to various situations, and to non-xpath did. 
It does not seem to click only one of the first that it is a thing of the following.

```
driver.find_element(:name, "xbutton").click
```

Answer (score 1):

I first saved, just for testing all the html part, in a file `test.html` as below :

```html
<input type="checkbox" value="021258" name="xbutton"></input>
<input type="checkbox" value="084192" name="xbutton"></input>
<input type="checkbox" value="095842" name="xbutton"></input>
<input type="checkbox" value="096325" name="xbutton"></input>
```

Now to check each of those check boxes, I wrote the code as below :

```rb
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to "file:///home/kirti/workspace/Ruby/test.html"

elements_to_click = driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//input[@name='xbutton']")
# below code will check only those check boxes which are not checked previously.
elements_to_click.each { |e| e.click if e.attribute('checked').nil? }
```

Below is the screenshot :

[image: **check box** :]